# Add a search feature in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I'm trying to add a search feature in React but I'm not sure how to pass a scoped variable from a function as a prop to my component.

You'll see below I created `[ newSearch, setNewSearch ]` to handle the state of the search. I added a variable `showSearchResults` in `handleSearch` in order to determine whether to show the entire `persons` array, or show search results in a ternary operator.

I'm not sure how to pass `showSearchResults` in the return statement of Phonebook. If I map through `showSearchResults`, in the return, i get a "'showSearchResults' is not defined  no-undef" error because it's scope is within the `handleSearch` function. Is there a simpler way to write this that will actually work?

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './components/Person';

const App = (props) => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
  ]); 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('');
  const [ newNumber, setnewNumber ] = useState('');
  const [ newSearch, setNewSearch ] = useState('');

  const addPerson = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const personObject = {
        name: newName,
        number: newNumber,
        id: persons.length + 1,

    };

    // Grab newName from personObject
    const { name } = personObject;
    const duplicate = persons.filter(
        person => 
        person.name.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase());
    if (duplicate.length < 1) {
        setPersons(persons.concat(personObject));
        setNewName('');
        setnewNumber('');
    } else {
        alert(`${name} is already added to phonebook`);
        setNewName('');
    };
  };

    const handleAdd = (event) => {
        setNewName(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleAddPhone = (event) => {
        setnewNumber(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSearch = (event) => {
        const search = event.target.value;
        setNewSearch(search);
        // console.log(newSearch);
        const showSearchResults = newSearch
        ? persons.name.filter(person => person.toUpperCase().includes(search.toUpperCase()))
        : persons;
    };

    
    

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
        <div>
            filter shown with <input value={newSearch} onChange={handleSearch}/>
        </div>
      <form onSubmit={addPerson}>
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleAdd}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          number: <input value={newNumber} onChange={handleAddPhone}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <ul>
        {persons.map(person => {
            return <Person key={person.name} person={person} number={person.number} />
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
};

export default App
```

Person.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Person = ({ person }) => {
    return (
        
        <li>{person.name} {person.number}</li>
    )
}

export default Person
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we need to set the state for the searchTerm .

```
 const handleSearch = (event) => {
    const search = event.target.value;
    setNewSearch(search);
  };
```

setting the `searchTerm` will trigger a re-render which we can use to filter the values.

```
const showSearchResults = newSearch
  ? persons.filter((person) =>
      person.name.toUpperCase().includes(newSearch.toUpperCase())
    )
  : persons;
```

Now in the return replace the persons with `showSearchResults`.

```
 {showSearchResults.map((person) => {
          return (
            <Person key={person.name} person={person} number={person.number} />
          );
        })}
```

[Example Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-modal-forked-z8v7s?file=/src/App.js:2097-2258)

Comment: Shyam, I'm not sure that I'm following. What you added is the same code I wrote, except you replaced `persons` in the return statement with `showSearchResults` and mapped through that. The problem I ran into with doing this is that the scope of `showSearchResults` is limited to the `handleSearch` function so I cannot access the `showSearchResults` variable in my return statement.

Comment: okay. so here is how the flow goes , when the component is rendered for the first time your search term will be '' . so the ternary operation will fail which will return your persons list . Now you type something in the search input , now in your `handleSearch` we are setting the state . Any state update in react will trigger a re-render . so your function now runs again . Now this time in your ternary operation you have a value in the search term . so now we filter the persons matching the search term . Let me know if you have any questions will be happy to explain .

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize that you moved the `showSearchResults` constant outside of `handleSearch`. Thanks.

Comment: You can also consider name with number to filter records
`const showSearchResults = persons.filter((person) => (person.name.toUpperCase().includes(newSearch.toUpperCase()) || person.number.toUpperCase().includes(newSearch.toUpperCase())))`

Answer (score 1):

You should add another state for the filtered persons

```
const [filteredPersons, setFilteredPersons] = useState([])
```

then in the handleSearch should be

```
const handleSearch = (event) => {
    const search = event.target.value;
    setNewSearch(search);
    // console.log(newSearch);
    const searchResults = newSearch
    ? persons.name.filter(person => person.toUpperCase().includes(search.toUpperCase()))
    : [];
    setFilteredPersons(searchResults)
};
```

and finally in the list

```
    <ul>
        {
         filteredPersons.length ? 
         filteredPersons.map(person => {
            return <Person key={person.name} person={person} number= {person.number} />
        })}
        :
        persons.map(person => {
            return <Person key={person.name} person={person} number={person.number} />
        })}
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);

const handleSearch = (event) => {
    const search = event.target.value;
    setNewSearch(search);
    setSearchResult(persons.filter(function(p) {return (p.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || (p.number.includes(search)));}));
};
```

```html
<div>
  filter shown with <input value={newSearch} onChange={handleSearch}/>
</div>
<div>
{searchResult && <p>Search Result</p> && searchResult.map((person, index) => <i>{person.name} {person.number}; </i>)}
</div>
```